# Extracting person name from file name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column of file names in the format `{lastName}_{firstName}_{termInfo}_{Progress_Report/Transcript}_randomstringofcharacters.pdf`

I would like to extract from this a variable that is `lastName, firstName` so that I can run a vlookup to match it to IDs. Is there an easy way to write a formula to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
=JOIN(", ", ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(A1, "{_}"), 9^9, 2))
```

[image]

for array:

```
=IFERROR(BYROW(A1:A, LAMBDA(x, JOIN(", ", ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(x, "{_}"), 9^9, 2)))))
```

[image]

Comment: `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN ...  9^9` I don't have a slight chance [(•_•)](https://i.imgur.com/hfEMPo8.gif)   - @Player0

Comment: @Osm I use 9^9 as "return all rows" but alright, in this case, it can be just 1 :)

Comment: I have never tried before in `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` I'll make a list of formulas example with a use of 9^9  - @Player0

Comment: @Osm QUERY, SORTN, ARRAY_CONSTRAIN, LOOKUP (MATCH, VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, XMATCH - if you rly want to force it)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 01**

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(A3,"_"),1,2), "\{|\}", ""))
```

[image]

### Option 02

```
=ArrayFormula(BYROW(A2:A, 
 LAMBDA(rg, IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,
 REGEXREPLACE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(rg,"_"),1,2), "\{|\}", "")),""))))
```

[image]